# React.js :You called `setState` with a callback that isn't callable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my piece of code, which works correctly (adds records), but throws an error after addition:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: enqueueCallback(...): You called
>   `setProps`, `replaceProps`, `setState`, `replaceState`, or
>   `forceUpdate` with a callback that isn't callable.

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return $.post('', {page: this.state},
      function(data) {
        this.props.handleNewPage(data);
        return this.setState(this.getInitialState(), 'JSON');
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }
```

There are no routes for now. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: tried this? `return this.setState(this.getInitialState, 'JSON');`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The second (optional) parameter to [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) is a callback function, not a string. You can pass a function that will be executed once the operation is completed.

Comment: deleting second argument 'JSON' really helped! Thanks so much :)

Comment: setState actually accepts a callback as the first argument as well: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: @HannesJohansson The first parameter can be either a **function** (not a callback, there's a difference), or an object. Either work fine. A callback is strictly a function to be *called back* when an operation was completed. That's not the case with setState's first argument.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Yes, you are correct, I'm guilty as charged of using the terminology poorly. But still, setState does accept a function as first argument. Which isn't contradicted by anything you say in your answer, it's just a side-note. The second argument should indeed be a callback and not a string.

Comment: @HannesJohansson Again, that is correct, but the problem was in the second parameter, not the first. Changing `this.getInitialState()` to `this.getInitialState` would not have solved it, because a. it wasn't the problem, and b. the signature is wrong.

Comment: Is there a callback to getinitialstate?

Answer (score 1):

You actually invoke `getInitialState` instead of providing a reference to the function itself on the line `return this.setState(this.getInitialState(), 'JSON');` and the second argument should never be anything but a callback function.

`this.setState` expects either a function that should return a state object as a single argument, or an object to merge the current state with (plus optionally a callback as a second argument to run after state has been set). So either you provide just a function that returns the new state, or you provide an object that the current state should be merged with as a first argument and a callback that will be executed after the state has been set as second argument.

Either `this.setState(this.getInitialState)` or `this.setState(this.getInitialState())` or `this.setState(newState, callback)`.

Check out the signature in the API [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html).

Comment: Your answer seems to suggest that the updater function returns the whole new state, when in fact it returns state changes just like passing an object.

The updater function signature is (prevState, props) => stateChange